# R Regressão por condição usando apply ou for

Tags: r, for, regressão, apply

Tenho a seguinte amostra:

```
x <- structure(list(POP = structure(c(1L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 
14L), .Label = c("pop1", "pop10", "pop11", "pop12", "pop13", 
"pop14", "pop15", "pop16", "pop17", "pop18", "pop19", "pop2", 
"pop20", "pop21", "pop3", "pop4", "pop5", "pop6", "pop7", "pop8", 
"pop9"), class = "factor"), a1 = c(91, 26.7, 51.9, 14, 0, 15.3, 
34.4, 19.1, 10.2, 52.5, 43.6, 13.1, 47.1, 34.7, 0, 58.9, 66.8, 
0, 0, 0, 0), a2 = c(92.9, 27.7, 54.1, 14.3, 0, 16.2, 35, 19.1, 
11.1, 52.5, 44.6, 13.4, 48.7, 34.4, 0, 59.5, 72.3, 0, 0, 0, 0
), a3 = c(92.6, 27.4, 54.7, 13.7, 0, 16.2, 36, 0, 11.1, 53.2, 
45.2, 13.7, 49.3, 0, 0, 59.5, 74.5, 0, 0, 0, 0), a4 = c(95.5, 
28.3, 57.3, 14.6, 0, 16.9, 36.9, 0, 11.8, 56.3, 47.1, 14, 53.2, 
0, 0, 62.7, 84.4, 0, 0, 0, 0), a5 = c(97.4, 28.6, 61.4, 14.3, 
0, 17.5, 36.9, 0, 12.4, 55.7, 47.4, 14.6, 53.8, 0, 0, 62.4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), a6 = c(97.7, 29.3, 63.3, 14.6, 0, 18.5, 38.8, 0, 
13.1, 57.3, 49, 15.3, 55.4, 0, 0, 62.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), a7 = c(102.2, 
0, 68.1, 14.6, 11.1, 20.1, 43.3, 0, 14.6, 64.9, 53.2, 0, 60.5, 
0, 0, 62.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), a8 = c(106.3, 0, 71.9, 14.3, 0, 19.7, 
45.8, 0, 15.9, 70.7, 57.3, 0, 67.8, 0, 10.5, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 
0), a9 = c(113.2, 0, 75.5, 15, 0, 21.7, 49, 0, 18.5, 73, 59.8, 
0, 0, 0, 14.7, 0, 0, 0, 10.4, 0, 0), a10 = c(114.9, 0, 75.2, 
15, 0, 22.6, 49.6, 0, 19.8, 73.8, 59.9, 0, 0, 0, 16.6, 0, 0, 
10.5, 10.5, 0, 0), a11 = c(114.9, 0, 75.5, 15.1, 0, 23.2, 50.6, 
0, 19.8, 74.6, 59.2, 0, 0, 0, 18.2, 0, 0, 10.5, 10.6, 0, 0), 
    a12 = c(115, 0, 76, 15.9, 0, 26.1, 0, 0, 22.7, 75.4, 60.8, 
    0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 10.3, 11.1, 0, 0), a13 = c(115.2, 11.6, 
    76, 16, 0, 26.6, 0, 0, 23.3, 75.5, 61.3, 0, 0, 0, 22.6, 0, 
    0, 10.7, 11.1, 0, 0), a14 = c(0, 11.6, 77.6, 0, 0, 29.5, 
    0, 0, 25.3, 76.2, 64, 0, 0, 0, 25.5, 0, 0, 11.6, 11.8, 10.2, 
    11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

E os dados anuais:

```
temp <- structure(list(ano = structure(c(1L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("a1", "a10", "a11", 
"a12", "a13", "a14", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", 
"a9"), class = "factor"), temp = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 13L, 
8L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Eu consigo extrair as regressões com as funções `apply`, quando eu tenho os dados completos nos 14 anos, fazendo uma limpeza nos dados e mantendo só as `pop` que tem a série completa de 14 anos.

Porém eu queria correr a regressão nos dados que não estão completos, uso o seguinte código:

```
y <- temp$temp

log_x <- apply(x[-1], 2, log)

model_list <- apply(log_x, 1, function(x) lm(x ~ y))

coef_list <- t(sapply(model_list, coef))

model_smry <- lapply(model_list, summary)
```

a função `apply`para no erro do log, que resulta em  `-inf` já que tem valores zero na base.

tem como correr a regressão até esse ponto antes do erro e calcular a regressão com o `y` correspondente ao ano que parou?

Por exemplo:

Sao 14 anos ou colunas
o ano 4 tem `-inf`
eu calculo a regressão só com os anos 1, 2 e 3 com o `y` correspondente a esses anos (parando a função `apply` no `-inf`). Fazendo isso para todas as linhas.

talvez dê para fazer isso com uma função `for` mas eu não sei como prosseguir, se puderem ajudar a começar ou indicar algo para estudar, já vai ser uma grande ajuda.

Comment: Eu não estou conseguindo reproduzir o teu erro. Por acaso a linha `log_x <- apply(log_x[-1], 2, log)` deveria ser `log_x <- apply(base[-1], 2, log)`? Além disso, para que serve o data frame `temp`? Por favor, reveja estes detalhes e edite a pergunta de modo que ela fique reproduzível.

Comment: Opa, desculpe. Acabei de arrumar o exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eu consegui complementar o código para não dar esse erro

segue a solução da função for:

```
for(i in (lav)){ # loop por linha
  # indices de coluna com valores -Inf
  indice_com_inf <- which(log_x[i,]<0)
  # criar lista de x sem os -inf
  x_list[[i]] <- log_x[i,-indice_com_inf]
  # novo y1 em lista, sem os indices de valores -Inf
  y_list[[i]] <- y[-indice_com_inf]
  # condição
  if (length(x_list[[i]]) >= 3) { #condição comprimento >=3
    #rodar regressão
    model_list[[i]] <- lm(x_list[[i]] ~ y_list[[i]])
  } else {
    model_list[[i]] <- NA #se não atender a condição, não fazer nada
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Então, espero que tenha entendido corretamente. Não é o jeito mais sofisticado, mas deve funcionar.
Vejamos os dados

```
 x
 #     POP   a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6    a7    a8    a9   a10   a11   a12   a13  a14
 #1   pop1 91.0 92.9 92.6 95.5 97.4 97.7 102.2 106.3 113.2 114.9 114.9 115.0 115.2  0.0
 #2   pop2 26.7 27.7 27.4 28.3 28.6 29.3   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  11.6 11.6
 #3   pop3 51.9 54.1 54.7 57.3 61.4 63.3  68.1  71.9  75.5  75.2  75.5  76.0  76.0 77.6
 #4   pop4 14.0 14.3 13.7 14.6 14.3 14.6  14.6  14.3  15.0  15.0  15.1  15.9  16.0  0.0
 #5   pop5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  11.1   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
 #6   pop6 15.3 16.2 16.2 16.9 17.5 18.5  20.1  19.7  21.7  22.6  23.2  26.1  26.6 29.5
 #7   pop7 34.4 35.0 36.0 36.9 36.9 38.8  43.3  45.8  49.0  49.6  50.6   0.0   0.0  0.0
 #8   pop8 19.1 19.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
 #9   pop9 10.2 11.1 11.1 11.8 12.4 13.1  14.6  15.9  18.5  19.8  19.8  22.7  23.3 25.3
 #10 pop10 52.5 52.5 53.2 56.3 55.7 57.3  64.9  70.7  73.0  73.8  74.6  75.4  75.5 76.2
 #11 pop11 43.6 44.6 45.2 47.1 47.4 49.0  53.2  57.3  59.8  59.9  59.2  60.8  61.3 64.0
 #12 pop12 13.1 13.4 13.7 14.0 14.6 15.3   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
 #13 pop13 47.1 48.7 49.3 53.2 53.8 55.4  60.5  67.8   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
 #14 pop14 34.7 34.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
 #15 pop15  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  10.5  14.7  16.6  18.2  21.0  22.6 25.5
 #16 pop16 58.9 59.5 59.5 62.7 62.4 62.7  62.7   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
 #17 pop17 66.8 72.3 74.5 84.4  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
 #18 pop18  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  10.5  10.5  10.3  10.7 11.6
 #19 pop19  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  10.0  10.4  10.5  10.6  11.1  11.1 11.8
 #20 pop20  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 10.2
 #21 pop21  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 11.0
 y <- temp$temp
 y
 # [1]  0  2  2  6  2  3 13  8  7  3  2  5  2  5
 log_x <- apply(x[-1], 2, log)
```

Aqui eu crio uma lista para receber os seus valores de interpolacao, que será feito por um loop (for)

```
 # acumula os valores de interpolacao
 model_list <- list()
```

Eu devo eliminar as linhas que nao tem nenhuma observacao válida

```
 # linhas em log_x com -Inf em todas as lacunas
 linhas <- c(3,6,9,10,11)
 # Linhas com Algum Valor (LAV) 
 lav <- (1:21)[-linhas]
 lav
 # [1]  1  2  4  5  7  8 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Agora eu crio um loop que i) remove as posicoes sem observacao, tanto no arquivo log_x como no y também; ii) Faz as interpolacoes

```
 for(i in (lav)){ # loop por linha
    # indices de coluna com valores -Inf
    indice_com_inf <- which(log_x[i,]<0)
    # novo log_x1, sem os indices de valores -Inf
    log_x1 <- log_x[i,-indice_com_inf]
    # novo y1, sem os indices de valores -Inf
    y1 <- y[-indice_com_inf]
    # novo 
   model_list[[i]] <- lm(log_x1 ~ y1) 
 }
```

Veja como fica as primeira cinco interpolacoes. Observe que, para os casos em que não houve nenhuma observação (linha `3`), a lista `model_list` fica vazia nessa posição

```
head(model_list,5)
#[[1]]
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = log_x1 ~ y1)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           y1  
#   4.614607     0.005504  
# 
#
#[[2]]
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = log_x1 ~ y1)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           y1  
#    3.23414     -0.04457  
#
#
#[[3]]
#NULL
#
#[[4]]
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = log_x1 ~ y1)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           y1  
#    2.68385      0.00109  
#
#
#[[5]]
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = log_x1 ~ y1)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           y1  
#      2.407           NA
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado. O processo funcionou como esperado. Mas no final está omitindo os valores ````NA````, você sabe algum jeito de fazer aparecer todos na lista. No fim do loop da a seguinte mensagem ````Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (não-NA) casos````

Comment: Muito obrigado cara. Você me deu o caminho certo. Abs

Comment: Opa, beleza. Por nada! Usei `head(model_list,5)` só pra mostrar as cinco primeiras regressões. Sobre o erro indicado, aqui não apareceu mesmo. Abs

Comment: Um pergunta, quando usa o ````head(model_list,5)````, a observação ````3```` fica com valor igual a ````NULL````, tem como calcular a regressão nela? pois a mesma apresenta a série completa dos dados, no caso daria para calcular com o ````y```` e suas 14 observações. Eu tentei alterar o loop para isso, mas não consegui.

Comment: Pelo menos nos dados do exemplo que passou, a observação `3` apareceu com todas as lacunas `-Inf`. No entanto, se você tiver outros dados com valores válidos, basta incluir o índice `3` no vetor `lav` --- assim essa posição entra no loop.